# XML parsing error when given url

Tags: xml

I have a problem with my XML syntax. Here is my code :

```
<scene thumburl="https://monserver.com/image.jpg?width=200&height=140&fit=crop&imgopt=1"> </scene>
```

And the resulting error :

> "The reference to entity "height" must end with the ';' delimiter."

I think that the parser does not consider: "https://monserver.com/image.jpg?width=200&height=140&fit=crop&imgopt=1" as a variable and try to parse it. How can I correct that?

P.S : This is an example URL, it is not supposed to work. The problem is about XML syntax, not my website.

Thank you!

Comment: Link not working. Please revise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `&` with `&amp;`

```
https://monserver.com/image.jpg?width=200&amp;height=140&amp;fit=crop&amp;imgopt=1
```

You can check this answer : [Whats the difference between & and &amp; in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776556/whats-the-difference-between-and-amp-in-html5)